# How to shoot missile similar to Galaga?

Tags: javascript, animation, dom-events, game-development

I am making a game similar to Galaga. I used to have my player at the middle of the screen and it would fire missiles in the direction of the click event, but now I want it to only fire straight up the screen (just like Galaga). How could I change my current code to accomplish this?

Here is my code:

```
class Missle {
    constructor(x, y, radius, color, velocity) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.radius = radius
        this.color = color
        this.velocity = velocity
    }

    draw() { // Draws the missle
        c.beginPath()
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0,
            Math.PI * 2, false) // Draws a 360 degree circle
        c.fillStyle = this.color //Sets the color to whatever color is passed in 
        c.fill() // Fills the circle
    }

    update() { // Updates classes properties over and over again
        this.draw()
        this.x = this.x + this.velocity.x
        this.y = this.y + this.velocity.y
    }
}

const missle = new Missle( // Passing parameters
    canvas.width / 2, (canvas.height / 2) * 1.75, // Sets missle beginning point at center
    5,
    'red',
    { // Creates an object for the velocity
        x: 1,
        y: 1
    }
)

fireBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => { // when we click it calls this function below
    const angle = Math.atan2(event.clientY - canvas.height / 2, 
        event.clientX - canvas.width / 2)
    const velocity = { //creates velocity object
        x: Math.cos(angle) * 1, // sets speed (velocity)
        y: Math.sin(angle) * -6 // sets speed (velocity)
    }
    missles.push(new Missle(
        player.x,
        player.y,
        //canvas.width / 2,
        //(canvas.height / 2) * 1.75,
        5,
        'rgb(250, 0, 0, .75',
        velocity
    ))
})
```

I know I need to change the way the velocity works unless there are better ways of doing so. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making the velocity use the angle between the center of the screen and the mouse position the velocity should just be your up vector. In other words change you velocity in the click event to be:

```
const velocity = {
        x: 0,
        y: -1
    }
```

You can google "vector math" to get a better understanding of where those values are coming from.